# ffmpeg error setting profile high

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using Zeranoe FFmpeg Build Version: 2a8dadb (2016-07-01)

My script :

> ffmpeg -i c:\AVerRecord170702a.avi -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow
>   -b:v 6000k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 145000k -profile:v high -level 4.1 -an AVerRecord170702b.mp4

I'm getting below error when I try to convert AVI to MP4

[image: error]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting the profile and level in the first place? Please don't make screenshots of text; simply copy and paste the text.

Answer (score 3):

High profile doesn't support 4:2:2 sampling scheme, so either use

```
ffmpeg -i c:\AVerRecord170702a.avi -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow
       -b:v 6000k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 145000k
       -profile:v high -level 4.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -an AVerRecord170702b.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i c:\AVerRecord170702a.avi -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow
       -b:v 6000k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 145000k
       -profile:v high422 -level 4.1 -an AVerRecord170702b.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks, this works: -level 4.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p